# python asyncio: keep to create task from a queue

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The scenario likes that I want to create a new task when receiving a new request and run it asynchronously. I am trying to use coroutine to solve this problem:

```
import asyncio
import queue
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

async def washing(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print('sleep ' + str(t))


async def main(request_queue):
    while  True:
        if not request_queue.empty():
            req = request_queue.get()
            # request_queue.task_done()
            if req == -1:
                break
            await washing(req)

task_num = 10
task_time = 0.5
def create_task(request_queue):
    for i in range(task_num):
        request_queue.put(task_time)
    request_queue.put(-1)
    print('create task finish')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    request_queue = queue.Queue()
    create_task(request_queue)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t_start = time.time() 
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([main(request_queue)]))
    print('total time ' + str(time.time() - t_start))
    print('serial time ' + str(task_num * task_time))
    loop.close()
```

But I find this code is executed serially. It runs 5.01s on my computer. How to fix it?

Edit:
I replace `await washing(req)` with `asyncio.create_task(washing(req))`
and

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([main(request_queue)])
```

with `asyncio.run(main(request_queue))`. Then I find the tasks are not exceuted because no infomation is printed.

```
async def washing(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print('sleep ' + str(t))
    
async def main(request_queue):
    while  True:
        if not request_queue.empty():
            req = request_queue.get()
            if req == -1:
                break
            asyncio.create_task(washing(req))

task_num = 10
task_time = 0.5
def create_task(request_queue):
    for i in range(task_num):
        request_queue.put(task_time)
    request_queue.put(-1)
    print('create task finish')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    request_queue = queue.Queue()
    create_task(request_queue)
    t_start = time.time() 
    asyncio.run(main(request_queue))
    print('total time ' + str(time.time() - t_start))
    print('serial time ' + str(task_num * task_time))
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Using `await washing(req)` does not call `washing` again until the first one is finished.

Comment: do you mean use ''' asyncio.create_task(washing(req))''' rather than use await?

Comment: Yes, that will start it in the background and will continue in the loop in `main`.

Comment: it reports 'Task was destroyed but it is pending!' if I just replace 'await washing(req)'.

Comment: That means some tasks were not done yet when the program ended. You need to wait for them to finish. If you just use `asyncio.run(main(request_queue))` instead of `loop.run_until_complete` it should do this automatically.

Comment: As updated in the problem description, the tasks are not  excuted.